# In Apple Pages, is there a function to search for names and tell me yes or no?

Tags: pages

In apple pages, I have a list of names created and it's gotten too big for me to scroll through and see if a name already exists.  I was curious if there is a way to make a function/formula to help me find names that are already inside my list and confirm them.

I have a table made with the names, (an A, B type column with 180+ rows of the names) And I want to add a function up top where I can type into a box and it returns if the name is already there or not.  Would the 'If' function work like this for me? or the 'Search' function? (if-true)"Name Found", (if-false)"No name Found") ?

I also understand that I can use the (Cmd + F shortcut to search for the names that way, but that's an extra window. I wondered if there was a function to solve this situation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And is there a reason you use Pages instead of Numbers?

Comment: So far I have tried an if statement. 
IF(B4='Table 1-1'::A2:A44," Name Found", "No Name Found"). 

B4 is the box where I want to search the name. And that gives me the return, 'No Name. Found', but I am having trouble in that the B4 doesn't react to the name I want to look for.

The Search Statement just errors out. (again, I could be placing my elements in the wrong order.) 
 SEARCH(B4='Table 1-1'::A2:A44,) or ('Table 1-1'::A2:A44), B4 ?) 

Table 1-1::A2:A44 is where I have my list of names to search from. And I want to type in a box to see if a name already exists.

Comment: And due to a dual-boot MBP 2012, I have stayed on Mojave 10.14.6 to allow my computer to play older games on the windows side/steam games.

Comment: Please [edit] and add additional info to the question and *not* in the comments... that is not what they are for...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function that can go through more than one cell at a time such as MATCH() or XMATCH().

Here is an example with MATCH(), assuming the name to be searched for is in cell B4 and the cells that contain the names to be searched through are in the column of cells A2 through A44:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B4,A2:A44,0)),"No Name Found","Name Found")
```

You can directly copy and paste this into the relevant Pages table if you like if the cell references are correct. Or you can paste it and then modify the cell references as you need.

Comment: This gets close! From =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B4, A2:A44, 0)), "No Name Found", "Name Found") For some odd reason, It will error or not show anything when I type a name in the (B4) box where I type the name to look for. 

So from what that code line I tested and made this:
IF(MATCH(A5,'Table 1-1'::A2:A44), "Name Found", "No Name Found")

And used box A5 this time, and I can get the "Name Found" or "No Name Found" to populate when I type in a name.  But now, it only works with one or 2 names or says that a name is found when I don't have the name actually listed. So that's my next issue.

Comment: Not sure why you are having trouble with the formula I gave as an example. It seems to work just fine when I try it. Are you making sure what you enter as the search term is being recognized by Pages? With any formula, for a newly entered search term to be recognized by Pages, you need to select another cell other than cell B4 in the table, for example, by pressing any of the arrow keys multiple times if necessary or the Tab ⇥ key, after entering the search term in cell B4.